# Fomular to automate project final status

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, calculated-column-formula, list-form, formula

Please i need help. I need a formula on share-point online list. I have 3 columns namely: Child care status, Education status, Micro business status. Each of the columns above have (Completed, Initiated, Approved, Partially completed) as their drop down options.

I intend to create a calculated field(Finalstatus) that returns:
**Completed** (If any of the 3 columns reads "completed")
**Initiated** (If any of the 3 columns reads "Initiated")
**partially completed** (If any of the 3 columns reads "Partially completed)
**Approved** (If any of the 3 columns reads "Approved")

Please consider ISBLANK for null values. Please i crave your indulgence to please share your ideas as to how i can get this done.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some logic issue with the current statement. This is not possible when any two of the three columns have different values.
For example, if *Child care status* reads **Completed** and *Education status* reads **Approved**, what value should *Finalstatus* return?

Would you please explain a bit more about the requirement? Or do you mean “If **all** of the 3 columns read the same value”?